# How to query documentdb and order based on a list with DateTime as a property

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working on documents with the following data structure (simplified):
As you can see, there's messages in it with different date times. There can be overlapping documents, so one document can have messages of 10 minutes ago and 5 minutes ago, another one can have messages of 15 minutes ago and 7 minutes ago.
What I want to query is the documents ordered by their 'max' datetime. So I want the document with the 5 minute ago one first, then document that contains the 7 minute ago one etc etc.

I'm currently wondering if Azure DocumentDB actually supports anything like this, since any trial of ordering it on the property and taking the first, last, MAX'ing it etc have failed. I was thinking of possibly saving it as epoch since that would be a native JSON type, but then I'd still need one of the above LINQ methods.

I'm querying using LINQ but any insights using SQL are obviously welcome. I know that these queries are possible in Mongo, but can't currently find anything online about this and all my efforts have proven to fail.

```
{
  "id": "02cbd75b-2f75-4050-861d-c2fa63edf3e9",
  "Messages": [
    {
      "DateTime": "2016-01-30T13:17:29.9922386+01:00",
      "Content": "Foo"
    },
    {
      "DateTime": "2016-01-30T13:27:29.9942405+01:00",
      "Content": "Bar"
    },
    {
      "DateTime": "2016-01-30T13:21:29.9942405+01:00",
      "Content": "FooBar"
    },
    {
      "DateTime": "2016-01-30T13:52:29.9942405+01:00",
      "Content": "BarFoo"
    }
  ]
}
```

Things I've tried ( a couple are obviously wrong) :

Attempt 1:

```
var threads = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MessageThread>("dbs/" + database.Id + "/colls/" + documentCollection.Id)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.MessagePosts
                                   .OrderBy(y => y.DateTime)
                                   .FirstOrDefault().DateTime)
                    .Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Attempt 2:

```
var threads = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MessageThread>("dbs/" + database.Id + "/colls/" + documentCollection.Id)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.MessagePosts
                                   .Max(y => y.DateTime))
                    .Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Attempt 3:

```
var threads = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MessageThread>("dbs/" + database.Id + "/colls/" + documentCollection.Id)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.MessagePosts[0].DateTime)
                    .Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Attempt 4:

```
var threads = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MessageThread>("dbs/" + database.Id + "/colls/" + documentCollection.Id)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.MessagePosts
                                   .OrderBy(y => y.DateTime))
                    .Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you sort client side? Alternatively, can you denormalize the max DateTime to the root level of the document?

Comment: Sorting client side is possible, but limits ideal since, if we're talking about say half a million records it becomes a bit too much. Denormalizing the max DateTime is my current idea as well but I'll retrieve more than needed since the messages can overlap. I was hoping there was something 'native' in the document db querying that would solve it directly.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no way to do that with a single query. If you host your node.js in the same data center as the DocumentDB collection, then the overhead is minimal for sorting "client" side. I say, do it the most straight forward way at first and measure to evaluate the need for optimization. Of course denormalizing will be more efficient on read. However, it may cost you more than you want on writes. Measure.

Comment: Thanks @LarryMaccherone, that confirms what I was thinking. I reckon for now I'll  go with a denormalized property.

Answer (score 2):

Azure DocumentDB currently does not support `ORDER BY` on nested array elements.

As Larry mentioned, you will either need to bring the property up outside of the array, or perform sorting on the application / client side.

That said, this is a feature worth having...

Can you please submit this feature and vote for it on the [DocumentDB feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb)? This helps the DocumentDB engineering team prioritize work on their end.

Comment: I just submitted it, thanks for your input! https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/12278685-support-querying-a-documents-list-with-objects-usi